# Laravel Email Greeting show Name instead of ID

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hello I wanted to ask regarding the Email Notification on Laravel, I have made a Status Notification wher I added this code

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $leaveStatus=$this->leave->status;
    if($leaveStatus==1){
        $leaveNotify=" approved  ";
    }
    else{
        $leaveNotify=" declined ";
    }
    return (new MailMessage)
    ->subject('Leave Status')
    ->greeting('Hello '.$this->leave->user_id)
    ->line('I hope you are doing well')
    ->line('Your requested leave of' . $this->leave->type. ' type has been ' .$leaveNotify)
    ->line('Leave type: ' .$this->leave->type)
    ->line('From dt :' .$this->leave->from)
    ->line('To dt :' .$this->leave->to);

}
```

This works very well the email is being sent in each change on a Leave Application so what I am looking for is the part of the greeting , the

> greeting('Hello '.$this->leave->user_id)

It shows the ID of the user instead of the first_name(which is a filed for the name) I have tried adding a ->first_name after the user_id but then it returns an error, the user_id doesn't have a foreign key that connects it with the users table its just a field which stores the id of each authenticated users but it works all the way here so im not sure that is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the notifiable variable passed into the function, which is the user the email is being sent to.

```
->greeting('Hello '.$notifiable->first_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add relation for `user` in that model. See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships . After that call it via `$this->leave->user->first_name`